How to deduce the integral form of $ J_n(z) $ from the generating function for Bessel functions?
I am working on the following question about the generating function for Bessel functions, as presented in Complex Analysis by Loukas Grafakos.
If we define the Bessel functions $ J_{n}(z) $ as those such that
$$
e^{\frac{z}{2} \cdot \left( \zeta - \frac{1}{\zeta} \right)}
$$
then we have that
$$
J_{n}(z) = \int_{C_1(0)} e^{z \left( \zeta - \frac{1}{\zeta} \right)} \frac{1}{\zeta^{n+1}} d\zeta.
$$
Here's my attempt:
$$
f(\zeta) = e^{z \left( \zeta - \frac{1}{\zeta} \right)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(z) \zeta^n, \quad 0 < |\zeta|.
$$
From my understanding, the Bessel functions $ J_n(z) $ arise as the Laurent coefficients of $ f(\zeta) $ in the expansion. To compute $ J_n(z) $, we are instructed to write:
$$
f(\zeta) = e^{z \zeta} e^{-\frac{z}{\zeta}},
$$
and expand each exponential term into series:

For $ e^{z \zeta} $, we use the Taylor expansion:
$$
   e^{z \zeta} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(z \zeta)^m}{m!}.
   $$

For $ e^{-\frac{z}{\zeta}} $, we use the Laurent expansion:
$$
   e^{-\frac{z}{\zeta}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k!} \zeta^{-k}.
   $$


Combining these two, we get:
$$
f(\zeta) = \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(z \zeta)^m}{m!} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k!} \zeta^{-k} \right).
$$
Expanding the product gives:
$$
f(\zeta) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^m}{m!} \cdot \frac{(-z)^k}{k!} \cdot \zeta^{m-k}.
$$
To collect terms with the same power of $\zeta^n $, I set $n = m - k $. This implies $ m = n + k $, and the double sum becomes:
$$
f(\zeta) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \zeta^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n+k}}{(n+k)!} \cdot \frac{(-z)^k}{k!}.
$$
The coefficient of $ \zeta^n$ is then:
$$
c_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n+k}}{(n+k)!} \cdot \frac{(-z)^k}{k!}.
$$
My questions are:
1.How does this development allow me to deduce the integral form of $ J_n(z) $? To be fair, the author specifically recommended expanding $ \exp\left(-\frac{z}{2 \cdot \zeta}\right) $ as a Laurent series. How does this fit into the overall computation?

Is my method for collecting terms with the same degree in $ \zeta $ correct? I am also revising product series and would be curious to know how convergence results about product series are related to Fubini's Theorem for double integrals.


Apart from a normalisation $z\mapsto z/2$ you have already found the solution more or less. Here it is how I would reason.
Let me to use the following definition of generating function
$$
g_z(\zeta) = e^{\frac{z}{2}(\zeta - 1/\zeta)}\tag{1}\label{gen}\quad .
$$
This function is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.
You have computed the Laurent expansion
$$
g_z(\zeta) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}c_n(z) \zeta^{n}\tag{2}
$$
with
$$
c_n(z) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(k+n)!}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k+n}\tag{2}\label{coefficients}\quad .
$$
Now consider
$$
\tilde g_z(\zeta) = \sum_{n\geq 0}c_n(z)\zeta^n\tag{3}
$$
which is entire (it is a Taylor series). Then from Taylor’s theorem we know that
$$
c_n(z) = \frac{\tilde g^{(n)}_z(0)}{n!} \tag{4}\label{coefficients2}\quad .
$$
In case one does not know, one checks that
$$
c_n’’(z)+\frac{1}{z}c_n’(z)+\left(1-\frac{n^2}{z^2}\right)c_n(z)=0
$$
i.e. the coefficients are solutions of the Bessel differential equation. Then we can say that
$$
c_n(z) = J_n(z)\tag{5}\label{bessel}\quad .
$$
By Cauchy’s integral formula given $\tilde g_z(\zeta)$ analytic
$$
\tilde g^{(n)}_z(\zeta) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\tilde g_z(\zeta’)}{(\zeta’-\zeta)^{n+1}}d \zeta’\tag{6}
$$
with $\gamma$ a closed path containing $\zeta$. Setting $\zeta=0$ and using \eqref{gen}, \eqref{coefficients2} and \eqref{bessel} you have that
$$
J_n(z) =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{e^{\frac{z}{2}(\zeta-1/\zeta)}}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta\tag{7}\quad .
$$
where $\gamma$ is a closed path containing the origin.
